# Multiple reports inside ReportViewer

Tags: vb.net, report, rdlc, reportviewer

I have a VB.Net software where i can make and print invoices by sending paramters and a sql to fill a datatable, to fill a "LocalReport" and show it inside a reportviewer.

What i need is to iterate through a list of invoice objects, and print 1 per page, inside the same reportviewer.

Can someone help me? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You mean repeat all reports for printing?

By doing select query you can get multiple reports in queue